# Robotframework list variable from variable file

Tags: list, variables, file-upload, robotframework

I'm having a problem reading a list variable from a file.
I have a file (variables.py) with 3 variables :

```
TEST1=212
TEST2=[111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666]
TESTS3="sadasd"
```

Both `${TEST1}` and `${TEST3}` are accessible (I get values from variable file)
But when I try to access second variable with `@{TEST2}[2]`, I get an error :

```
FAIL : Non-existing variable '@{TEST2}[2]'
```

This only happens, if I try to use variables from file. If I create list variable in RIDE, I can easly access it with `@{Variable}[{$index}]`

If I try this syntax : `${TEST2}[2]`, I get :

```
'[111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666][2]'
```

So robotframework knows that there is a variable with given name, but doesn't know that it's a list variable.
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7):

To distinguish explicitly between a list that is a value of a scalar variable and a list variable, you have to use `LIST__` prefix for @{vars} in the variable file. See [Robot Framework User Guide: Creating variables directly](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-variables-directly)  for details.

In your case, this would be:

```
LIST__TEST2 = [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666]
```

In general, there are three ways to initialize lists in [variable files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files):

```
STRINGS = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
LIST__STRINGS = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
```

Do not confuse this with the syntax for the `*** Variables ***` section, where initializing a list would be:

```
*** Variables ***
@{STRINGS}     | one | two | three | four
```

You can access individual elements in a list assigned to scalar variable like this:

```
${TEST2[0]}
```

Comment: Now I feel kind of dumb. Went through Variable section several times, but didn't see that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just fixed the link.

Comment: sneaky finnish lesson of the day :D

Comment: Thanks a lot.. :)